# Creating a test hub so users can trigger and watch Selenium RC tests running

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc

Appologies if this is a bit of a noob queston.

I have Selenium RC setup on a server and a test hub application.
When a user selects to run a test from the test hub, which browsers will the test be run on. Those on the server or those on the users machine?

Basically I want my test hub app to serve 2 purposes,  for a user to trigger and watch a test to be run and 2ndly for the underlying tests to be accessible so they can be run automatically by the build server using Cruise Control.

Answer (score 1):

I personally wouldnt worry about running the tests on the persons PC and go for the option of video recording the tests while they run so that the person can have a look at the video once the test is complete.

I would set up a Selenium Grid that when you trigger a test it will then push the test to the grid and then record them. I did a [blog post](http://www.theautomatedtester.co.uk/blog/2010/castro-selenium-video.html) in May that describes how to set up video recording on Linux.

If you don't have the time or hardware to set this all up you can always trigger the tests to run on [Sauce Labs](http://saucelabs.com) and they will record the video for you automatically so that people can see them

Comment: Your a star!  Yeah I've looked at Sauce Labs  but, there is no budget really.  If the test wants to see the tests running they can RDP to the machine.  Ultimately the tests will be run in the wee hours triggered by Cruise Control.  The fact you could watch them is cherry on the cake.